# How can I edit a meta description

Tags: wp-head

A `shortcode` that I'm using in the beginning of each post is somehow getting into the `meta description`. After trying to figure out why I decided to simply do a `preg_replace` for the meta description, however it seems to be much trickier than I initially thought:

```
function remove_shortcode() {

global $post;

if ( is_single() && in_category( 'shortcode' ) ) {

    $content = preg_replace('{\[shortcode\]}','',$content);
    return $content;
}   
else {
    return $content;
}
}
add_filter('wp_head', 'remove_shortcode');
```

But that does nothing. So I'm guessing it's either not possible, or should be done somehow differently. Searching around didn't provide any help either as no one seems to have had a need to modify their meta descriptions.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you display the meta description?

Comment: I guess it's either a theme thing or a global wordpress thing.

Comment: Yeah you should get into the shortcode and see how it's ending up in your meta tags, not let it happen then try and replace it after.

Comment: But is there a way to do what I want to do and edit the meta description using preg_replace?

Comment: It depends on what is generating the meta description. I would deactivate all plugins and enable a default theme, then one by one, test theme, then one plugin at a time to figure out what is generating the initial meta description. That should give you a better idea of how to adjust it.